# Unable to add membership types

Tags: civimember

I'm very new to this but I can't seem to find an answer to our problem on any of the help pages.

I am trying to simply add a new membership type. There were three membership types already setup with the initial installation, which I was able to modify to our specifications. But when I try to add a new membership type, I am unable to select anything in for Membership Organization, financial type, or membership type plan (pull-downs). There is nothing there.

Any help would be appreciated. We have 5 membership types and need to be able to add two more to the existing three.

Attaching screen shot here. Thank you.

[image: Unable to select anything in required field pull-downs.]

Comment: suggest you attach a screenshot of one of the existing 'types' - might answer a bunch of questions that will get fired your way

Comment: I believe I have this same problem. I am unable to select anything in the fields mentioned. However, once I close the modal dialog, the drop down box for Financial type (to use this as an example) is now visible and I can select something. At that point it is too late because the dialog has already closed (had to cancel it since I couldn't complete). I don't believe I can use this software without being able to add more membership types. I hope someone can help with this! Update: I have a workaround for this problem; I created new membership types directly in the database by copying an existin

Answer (score 1):

Normally membership type organization dropdown will be empty. so, please type a space and wait for the search - which will list you all contact in the list

For more reference please read the below documentation

Create new membership type:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC21/Membership+Types

Create new organization:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Create+New+Organization+Contact

Create new financial type:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Configure+Financial+Types

Create financial account:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Configure+Financial+Accounts

These above document should help you in creating new membership type - if you need more help please let me know so i will give a screen shot of all the above

I guess this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a permission issue - make sure you are logged in as an administrator and/or have all the required permissions (including acl if you use it).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a GUI issue -> reload the page and check your browser's console to see if you get any Errors.